# Addition and subtraction within bounds

Tags: javascript

How would you write the following in JavaScript:

```
    Row-=21;
    if (Row < 1) {
        Row = 1;
    }
```

Comment: That looks like valid JavaScript already to me.

Comment: @Chris: Hrm? I've always used -= to decrease a variable by a value. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

Comment: No, it does not.  `Row = -21`, would set it to negative 21.  'Row =- 21' would decrement by 21.  `Row-=21` is invalid syntax, and would result in a  a syntax error.

Comment: @Chris: Can you point me to a reference?  Are we talking about the same language?  I've written JavaScript for years.

Comment: @Chris: try this in firebug: var x = 10;x =- 1;console.log(x); and you'll see the output is -1.

Comment: Yes, you are correct , I was mistaken.  :)  Long day!

Comment: @Chris: No problem. Glad to know I wasn't going crazy!

Comment: Nope... I'm more drunk than you are.  Today.  :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Row = Math.max( Row-21, 1);
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to be able to set a minimum and/or maximum range, you could prototype your own function into Number.

```
Number.prototype.adjust = function( adj, min, max ) {
    if( isNaN( min ) ) min = -Infinity;
    if( isNaN( max ) ) max = Infinity;
    var res = this + ~~adj;
    return res < min ? min : res > max ? max : res;
};
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Row = Row.adjust( -21, 1, 50 ); /* adjustment, min, max */
```

- 1st argument is the adjustment
- 2nd argument is the minimum range *(pass null for no min)*
- 3rd argument is the maximum range *(pass null or leave blank for no max)*

Answer (score 2):

```
Row = Row > 22 ? Row - 21 : 1;
```

Comment: Technically, yes.  However, there's nothing wrong with the original, and it's arguably clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
row-=21;
if (row < 1) {
    row = 1;
}
```

It seems like already-valid JS.

The only difference would be that you would need to declare your "row" variable as:

```
var row = 0;
```

Comment: `row-=21` is not a valid line of JS - the operator is `=-`

Comment: @Chris - that's 3 times in one post. You're incorrect, the operator is -=. Using =- will simply assign a negative value to the target variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's a way that replaces the role of the operator with a function:

```
function makeBoundedOp( bound, addOrSub ){
  var newfunc = function newfunc(value,change){
    if( addOrSub === 'add' ){
       var upperbound = bound; 
       return (value+change > upperbound) ? upperbound : value+change; 
    } else {
       var lowerbound = bound;
       return (value-change < lowerbound) ? lowerbound : value-change;               
    }
  }  
  return newfunc;
}
```

Now build up any special-purpose bounded operator functions you need:

```
var subtractBoundedOne = makeBoundedOp(1,'subtract');
var subtractBoundedTen = makeBoundedOp(10,'subtract');
var addBoundedFifty = makeBoundedOp(50,'add');
```

Then:

```
var row = 20;

subtractBoundedOne(row,12); // 8
subtractBoundedTen(row,12); // 10
addBoundedFifty(row,37); // 50
```